# InfluxDB how to use OR in a query?

Tags: mysql, influxdb

Consider the table vital:

```
time                                CO2    bloodSugar   patientId
2015-10-15T08:45:11.015937347Z             0.04         1
2015-10-15T12:31:38.79680289Z       0.3                 1
2015-10-16T08:53:53.974538938Z             0.07         1
```

I am trying to get points that have either CO2 value or bloodSugar value and the query I am using:

```
select * from vital where ( bloodSugar != null or CO2 != null ) and time > now() - 100w
```

There should be 3 points returned, however the database just returns the points with the condition `bloodSugar != null` (1st and 3rd lines). Is there a problem with the query or the database and how can I fix this?

InfluxDB version: 0.9.4.2

Answer (score 0):

Now that I've read up on influxdb, you are supposed to be using time series data, so for that moment in time, you have no data.

It would be acceptable to set your `NULL` values to 0 or -1.

Comment: The database produces an error when this is used. The error:
`ERR: error parsing query: found IS, expected ) at line 1, char 40`

Comment: Ive added 2 more attempts, give those a crack

Comment: Both attempts produce the same result with the select statement in my question, unfortunately. (Just lines having `bloodSugar != null` are returned)

Comment: flip them around `select * from vital where ( CO2 != null or bloodSugar != null ) and time > now() - 100w` and see if you get CO2 ones back.

Comment: I used -1 for the values that are not present and OR works as expected if -1 is used in the query instead of null. I think there is a bug with the null values.

Comment: See my answer, Ive just had a read of the influx doc. `Null` isnt supported correctly I dont think, so you could do that if you wanted, or use -1 as a 'no data' equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

InfluxDB does not store null values. You can query for the existence or not of a value, but you cannot query for `null`.

Try `select * from vital where ( bloodSugar !~ /.*/ OR CO2 !~ /.*/ ) and time > now() - 100w`

Comment: The database doesn't return any lines when this command is used. No error though.

Comment: An empty return means no points matched. I'll take a look at the syntax again

Comment: Are `bloodSugar` and `CO2` tags or fields? Regex matching only works against tags, not fields.

Comment: If they are fields then you cannot use regular expression matching against them. Also, since `null` values are not stored you can't query for `WHERE bloodSugar = null` or `!= null`. In addition, queries that use fields in the `WHERE` clause are not performant. I think perhaps your schema is not what it should be, or your use case doesn't necessarily fit InfluxDB.